# Programatically create user that needs admin aproval

Tags: users

When creating a new user with user_save, it seems to get the "approved" role automatically, even though I pass an empty array to `$user->roles`.

How can I force the programatically created user to need admin approval before being activated?

Comment: I suppose (but did not check) that you can set the status to 0. That should create a 'disabled user'. I do however not know if that will trigger all mails that would otherwise be sent with the UI.

Comment: Thanks. I think status 0 is a blocked user though - user can't log in, doesn't get any errors, and no mails are triggered when the user is activated.

Comment: I am pretty sure the admin approval does nothing more than setting the status to 1 e.g. from blocked to active. There is no such thing as an "approved" role.

Comment: Whats the english name of the user role with id 2? It is enabled by default and checkbox is disabled in backend.

Comment: I am sorry, but a fresh Drupal installation creates the anonymous user as uid=0 and the admin as uid=1. There is no user 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1**

**Not need to follow it compulsary**

You don't need any third-party modules. Drupal core has the option to verify the email the user enters, and the option for the administrator user to approve the accounts users create. In Drupal 7, those settings are on /admin/config/people/accounts.
[image]

**Step2**

- Once you prepare your $user object and use it on user_save function you have to follow below steps to send the mail.

```
$userData = user_save($user);
$account = user_load($userData->uid);
$op = 'register_pending_approval';
$status = _user_mail_notify($op, $account);
```